# Why Tooltip is not moving with mouse?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, graph

This is a code for making pie chart.

I have added 2 functionalities to pie chart. First one is to increase the arc size when mouse hovers on it.

Second is that when i hover, tooltip displays y position of mouse and this tooltip moves with mouse.

But problem with me is that. Tooltip Text is not moving with movement of mouse.

*I have seen various stack overflow links for this* but i am unable to find solution. Below i have also attached links that so that the question is not marked duplicate.

**Please do not give me a new code for tooltip. Correct this one**.

Below are the links that i have already visited
[Why is my D3.js tooltip not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43970986/why-is-my-d3-js-tooltip-not-working)
[D3 - Positioning tooltip on SVG element not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153074/d3-positioning-tooltip-on-svg-element-not-working)
[Tooltips not showing on mouse move and mouse over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148196/tooltips-not-showing-on-mouse-move-and-mouse-over)

Link of jsfiddle :- https://jsfiddle.net/uoh1bsrp/
Thanks,
Shubham Sharma

```js
width = 600
height = 600

svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width',width).attr('height',height).append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) + ',' + (height / 2) + ')');
a = [2,5,7]
pie = d3.pie()
radius = 150

arc = d3.arc().innerRadius(0)
.outerRadius(radius);
arcs = svg.selectAll('arc').data(pie(a)).enter().append('g')
arcs.append("path").attr('d',function(d){return arc(d)})

tooltip  = svg.append('text')

color = ['red','green','blue']
path = d3.selectAll('path').style('fill',function(d,i){return color[i]})

path.on('mouseover',handlemouseover)
path.on('mouseout',handlemouseout)
path.on('mousemove',handlemousemove)



function handlemouseover(){
 d3.select(this).attr('d',function(d){return d3.arc().innerRadius(0)
    .outerRadius(180)(d)});

}


function handlemousemove(){
 // svg.append('text').text(function(){return 'shubham'}).style('top',(d3.event.layerY + 10)+'px').style('left',(d3.event.layerX + 10) + 'px')
 tooltip.text(function(){return d3.event.layerX}).style('top',(d3.event.layerY + 10)+'px').style('left',(d3.event.layerX + 10) + 'px').style('display','block');
}


function handlemouseout(){
 d3.select(this).attr('d',function(d){return d3.arc().innerRadius(0).outerRadius(radius)(d)});
 tooltip.style('display', 'none');
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-path.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-shape.v1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: But where is the code?

Comment: I have added it. It accidently got deleted earlier.

Comment: Can please you create a jsfiddle.

Comment: This is jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/uoh1bsrp/

Comment: @Andrew Please take a look at it.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma, I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are trying to increase `top` property of `text` tag in SVG. This porperty just doesn't work. You can use translate instead of it or just use tags like div or span.
Check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fr71t0o3/3/:

```
function handlemousemove() {
  // svg.append('text').text(function(){return 'shubham'}).style('top',(d3.event.layerY + 10)+'px').style('left',(d3.event.layerX + 10) + 'px')
  tooltip
    .text(function() {
        return d3.event.layerX;
    })
    .style('transform', `translate(${d3.event.layerX - 300}px, ${d3.event.layerY - 300}px)`)
    .style('display', 'block').style('color','red');
}
```

I'm not sure about offset of tooltip, if you want it moving with the mouse move you can use mouse coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.style('left', /*[...]*/)` and `.style('top', /*[...]*/)`  you can use `.attr('x', [...])` and `.attr('y', [...])`

Also, you have to substract `height/2` from `y` and `width/2` from `x`, as the `x` and `y` attributes move text **relative to its parent**:

```js
width = 600
height = 600

svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width',width).attr('height',height).append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) + ',' + (height / 2) + ')');
a = [2,5,7]
pie = d3.pie()
radius = 150

arc = d3.arc().innerRadius(0)
.outerRadius(radius);
arcs = svg.selectAll('arc').data(pie(a)).enter().append('g')
arcs.append("path").attr('d',function(d){return arc(d)})

tooltip  = svg.append('text')

color = ['red','green','blue']
path = d3.selectAll('path').style('fill',function(d,i){return color[i]})

path.on('mouseover',handlemouseover)
path.on('mouseout',handlemouseout)
path.on('mousemove',handlemousemove)



function handlemouseover(){
 d3.select(this).attr('d',function(d){return d3.arc().innerRadius(0)
    .outerRadius(180)(d)});

}


function handlemousemove(){
 // svg.append('text').text(function(){return 'shubham'}).style('top',(d3.event.layerY + 10)+'px').style('left',(d3.event.layerX + 10) + 'px')
 tooltip.text(function(){return d3.event.layerX}).attr('y',(d3.event.layerY - height/2 + 10)+'px').attr('x',(d3.event.layerX - width/2 + 10) + 'px').style('display','block');
}


function handlemouseout(){
 d3.select(this).attr('d',function(d){return d3.arc().innerRadius(0).outerRadius(radius)(d)});
 tooltip.style('display', 'none');
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-path.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-shape.v1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to append a div and add css styles to it.

Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/amp42fjn/

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
        .append("div")
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("z-index", "10")
        .style("visibility", "hidden")
        .text("a simple tooltip");  



    path.on("mouseover",handlemouseover)
    path.on("mousemove", handlemousemove)
    path.on("mouseout", handlemouseout);


            function handlemouseover(){
                d3.select(this).attr('d',function(d){return d3.arc().innerRadius(0)
                .outerRadius(180)(d)});
                tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");

            }
            function handlemousemove(){

tooltip.text(function(){return d3.event.layerX}).style('top',(d3.event.layerY + 10)+'px').style("top",
        (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(d3.event.pageX+10)+"px");
            }
            function handlemouseout(){
                d3.select(this).attr('d',function(d){return d3.arc().innerRadius(0).outerRadius(radius)(d)});

        tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
            }
```